# Gradle and Bintray Plugin: Cannot cast _Decorated

Tags: java, maven, gradle, bintray

In attempting to publish my set of plain Java libraries on Bintray using the Gradle Bintray plugin, I got the following error upon running the 'bintrayUpload' task:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'task ':bintrayUpload'' with class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask_Decorated' to class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask'
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask.getCachedRepositories(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:663)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask_Decorated.getCachedRepositories(Unknown Source)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask.getRepository(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:683)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask.checkPackageAlreadyCreated(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:510)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask$_bintrayUpload_closure5.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:255)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask$_bintrayUpload_closure5.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy)
at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayUploadTask.bintrayUpload(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:470)
```

The publish tasks work perfectly; it's just the Bintray upload that is failing.

Each library is a submodule in a root project.

The Maven/Bintray part of the Gradle file in one of my submodules looks like this:

```
//Bintray
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}
def bintrayPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("bintray.properties")
def bintrayProperties = new Properties()
bintrayProperties.load(new FileInputStream(bintrayPropertiesFile))


apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication){
            from components.java
            groupId bintrayProperties['bintrayRepository']
            artifactId project.name
            version rootProject.libraryVersion
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
bintray {
    user = bintrayProperties['bintrayUser']
    key = bintrayProperties['bintrayKey']
    publications = ['mavenJava']
    pkg {
        repo = bintrayProperties['bintrayRepository']
        name = project.name
        userOrg = bintrayProperties['bintrayOrganization']
        licenses = [bintrayProperties['bintrayLicense']]
        vcsUrl = bintrayProperties['bintrayVcs']
        version {
            name = rootProject.libraryVersion
            released  = new Date()
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my Gradle build file?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your root project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
```

I would love to be enlightened as to why this fixes it, but it does.

Comment: Because that problem seems to be happening with the plugin version 1.8.4. Downgrading to 1.8.0 apparently fixes it (thanks, it worked for me :D ).

Comment: 1.8.4 works fine for me after adding this block (@1.8.4).